# df1.equals(df2) fails on same csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which must be equal as is evident from the following code:

```
df1.to_csv("part2_trains.csv",index=False)
df2= pd.read_csv("part2_trains.csv",index_col=False)
print df2.dtypes
print df1.dtypes
print df1.equals(df2)
```

But the output of this is not what I expect:

```
hour_id                  int64
device_id                int64
os_id                    int64
browser_id               int64
first_category_name     object
city                    object
state_code              object
referer                 object
dow                     object
mobile_model            object
screen_size             object
impression               int64
revenue                float64
dtype: object
hour_id                  int64
device_id                int64
os_id                    int64
browser_id               int64
first_category_name     object
city                    object
state_code              object
referer                 object
dow                     object
mobile_model            object
screen_size             object
impression               int64
revenue                float64
dtype: object
False
```

Why does df1.equals(df2) return False though they are one and the same thing?

Comment: Could any of your entries contain `nan`?

Comment: @kabanus Yes. df1 contains some nan values. Does it affect the equality?

Comment: What is the index of `df1`? If it's not a regular RangeIndex they will be different for sure.

Comment: @user2285236    df1.index returns RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1298610, step=1)

Comment: Try `df1.eq(df2, axis=0).all()` and try the same with `axis=1`. If they return False you can identify which point is different.

Comment: My hunch was wrong, @user2285236 corrected me - `nan` is treated as you would expect in `pandas`. What does the `index` of `df2` return?

Comment: axis =0 returns False with some columns, I'll try to debug , thanks!!

Comment: I also suggest you post a minimal data frame that can reproduce this error, we can look at it.

Comment: `df2` will have a "reset index" while `df1` might have some other index (e.g. reversed) - that could also be a reason for the inequality